# Make a ratio between variables based on one criterion in a loop and keep several variables

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 trapping sessions in each season of the year for 3 years (The real database have more than 100 seasons and 800 trapping seasons).
For each trapping season I have 3 binomial variables ("Non_Breeder", "Potential_Breeder" and "Breeding").

```
# example    
    Year <- c(rep(2000,12), rep(2001,12), rep(2002,12))
    Season <- c(rep (seq(1:4), each=3,3))
    Trap_Session <- seq(1:36)
    Non_Breeder <- (rbinom(36, 1, prob=0.5))
    Potential_Breeder <- (rbinom(36, 1, prob=0.8))
    Breeding <- (rbinom(36, 1, prob=0.4))
    Month <- sample(12, 36, replace = TRUE)
    db <- cbind (Year, Season, Trap_Session, Non_Breeder, Potential_Breeder,     Breeding)
    db <- as.data.frame (db)
```

I would like to calculate "(Potential_Breeder + Breeding) / (Non_Breeder + Potential_Breeder + Breeding)" for each season keeping the variables "Year", "Season" and "Ratio".

I have tried using the function `table` but I don't know how to automate making a loop for each season and keeping the variables "Year", "Season" and "Ratio".

For example:
If I have the following data:

```
   Year Season Trap_Session Non_Breeder Potential_Breeder Breeding 
1  2000      1            1           1                 1        0  
2  2000      1            2           1                 1        0 
3  2000      1            3           0                 1        0  
4  2000      2            4           0                 1        1  
5  2000      2            5           1                 1        1  
6  2000      2            6           1                 1        1
```

I would like to get:

```
Year Season Ratio
2000     1  0.6 # (3/5)
2000     2  0.75 # (6/8) 

#Explanation of the calculation 
# 2000 Season 1
(3 Potential_Breeder / 5 (3Potential_Breeder+2 Non_Breeder)
# 2000 Season 2
(3Potential_Breeder + 2Breeding / 2Non_Breeder + 3Potential_Breeder +2Breeding)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: you forget the Month variable

Comment: Thanks, I have changed Month by Season. Now the question is right

Comment: thanks for the update, I edited my answer, which now works, but you still have a mistake in your calculations: the example output you give is calculated incorrectly, check it again the results should be:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(db)[ , .("Ratio" = sum(Potential_Breeder, Breeding) /
              sum(Non_Breeder, Potential_Breeder, Breeding)), by = .(Year, Season)]
```

this adds a Variable called "Ratio" (name it as you wish) to your existing data grouping by Year and Season,

same with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(db, Year, Season) %>% summarise("Ratio" = sum(Potential_Breeder, Breeding) /
 sum(Non_Breeder, Potential_Breeder, Breeding))
```

which both gives the following output given the db in your OP:

```
    Year Season     Ratio
 1: 2000      1 0.8000000
 2: 2000      2 0.5000000
 3: 2000      3 0.6000000
 4: 2000      4 0.8000000
 5: 2001      1 0.6666667
 6: 2001      2 0.8000000
 7: 2001      3 0.8000000
 8: 2001      4 0.6000000
 9: 2002      1 1.0000000
10: 2002      2 0.5000000
11: 2002      3 0.8571429
12: 2002      4 0.6666667
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help. 
Your code works at the level of Trapping session, but it does not summary at Season level (your Month, sorry I have previously written bad; I have corrected the question).

Comment: edited the answer, is this what you want? just replace the `by = ` with whatever variable you wanna group by in data.table and with in dplyr replace `group_by = `with whatever you need

Comment: Instead of the command "group_by=Season", It keeps grouping by "Trap_Session"

Comment: the variable names in your opening post are all mixed up, please fix your opening post there is no variable called "Breeder" there is only a variable called "Breeding",  thats why, it should work now

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now they question was corrected. Regarding the question and answering your previous command: I want to sum all counts for "Non_Breeder", "Potential_Breeder" and "Breeding" for each "Season" and later make the calculation. In this way I will get the ratio for each season.

Answer (score 1):

Month is missing in your data construct! Nevertheless, one solution:

```
# Columns you want to group by
grp_cols <- names(db)[-c(3,4,5,6)]

# Convert character vector to list of symbols
dots <- lapply(grp_cols, as.symbol)

db %>%
  group_by_(.dots = dots) %>%
  summarise(SumNB = sum(Non_Breeder), SumB = sum(Breeding), SumPB = sum(Potential_Breeder)) %>%
  mutate(Ratio = (SumPB + SumB) / (SumNB + SumPB + SumB))
```

Should do it.

EDIT: Corresponding to your 3rd comment of grrgrrblas answer, this script sums up all counts for B, NB and PB and subsequently calculates the ratio.

Comment: you are missing the grouping part: `group_by(db, Season)`

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work because it is adding the values for each trapping_sesion, when I want the summary. For example if I have two rows with: 
  `NB PB   B 
     1     1   0 
     0     1   1`  
Your code is adding 0.5+1=1.5 
Whereas I want that it makes: (2PB+1B)/(1NB+2PB+B)=0.7